# Why does the number 10 get output in each iteration and how can I fix this?

Tags: c, loops, char, ascii

I have a for loop, which I want to get the input from the user and print the associated ascii value. But it only asks for the user input in the second iteration, which is followed and preceded by the output 10. I tried to get rid of new-line characters, but it still prints out 10.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
int number;

printf("Enter the number:");
scanf("%i", &number);
for( ; number > 0; number--){
  char character;
  printf("Give a char: \n");
  scanf("%c", &character);
  printf("The associated ascii value is %i \n", character);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is because you are reading a single character instead of a "number".  When the user presses Return, that puts a newline character in the buffer.  The next time around the loop, you read that character next.  The ASCII value for newline happens to be 10.

Comment: What is the point of the program?  This seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: **Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and the documentation of your C compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe simpler (**though using `scanf()` for user input is not recommended**)

```
    scanf(" %c", &character);
    //     ^                  skip otional leading whitespace
```

Your whole program using `fgets()` for user input (and my indentation, spacing, style; sorry)

```
#include <stdio.h>  // printf(), fgets()
#include <stdlib.h> // strtol()

int main(void) {
    int number;
    char buffer[100];                  // space enough
    printf("Enter the number:");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
    number = strtol(buffer, 0, 10);    // error checking missing
    for (; number > 0; number--) {
        printf("Give a char: ");
        fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin); // reuse buffer, error checking missing
        if (buffer[0] != '\n') {
            printf("The associated ascii value of '%c' is %i.\n", *buffer, *buffer);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. `getchar()` will read the extra newline character from buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
int number;

printf("Enter the number:");
scanf("%i", &number);
for( ; number > 0; number--){
  char character;
  printf("Give a char: ");
  getchar();
  scanf("%c", &character);
  printf("The associated ascii value is %i \n", character);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you happen to compile and test this code before you posted it?

Comment: Ya, I suppose it would after all. it's not immediately clear why however. I would have just ingested the newline character in the `scanf` call.

Comment: The `scanf()` function skips leading whitespace automatically before trying to parse conversions other than characters.

Comment: Newlines aren't usually "leading white space" when you request user input.  `scanf("%i\n"...)` and `scanf("%c\n"...)` would be much more in-line with the apparent intent of the program, and make it more obvious as well.

Comment: In other words, don't leave crap in the input buffer, and you won't need any extra function calls.

Comment: @jwdonahue - Your suggested `scanf("%…\n"...)` don't behave well when a new prompt is to be printed after the input line. Did *you* happen to compile and test this code before you posted it? ;-)

Comment: @Armali How is it any different than the `getchar` call that removes the newline character from the input? Define what "does not behave well" actually means.  I think it's always behaved exactly as expected.

Comment: @jwdonahue - If you can't be bothered to try and see... well, the `getchar` removes exactly one character, which (for well-formed input) is the newline, as you say; on the other hand, for the `\n` in the `scanf()` this from the C standard's description of the `fscanf` function applies: _A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the
first non-white-space character…_. I. e. the first scanf doesn't return before it has gathered the next input, which the user has to enter before the prompt for it could be printed, so behaving expectedly, but not **well**.

Answer (score 0):

regarding;

```
scanf("%c", &character);
```

the first time through the loop the '\n' is input.

on all following passes through the loop, the `scanf()` fails, so the value in `character` does not change.

This is a prime example of why your code should be error checking.

for instance, to error check the call to `scanf()`:

```
if( scanf("%c", &character) != 1 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "scanf for a character failed\n" );
    break;
}
```

the `1` is because the `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful: `input format conversion specifiers` or EOF and it is best to assure the 'positive' status.